# Adding multiple object attributes to the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object from which I'd like to take some attributes and put them into a brand new array. I can do that for one attributes, but I can't do with multiple. I want to take specific attributes (title and year in this case) and put their values in the new array. It should look like this: const movies1 = ["AAA", "BBB"]. I'm not sure if I can do this with map or I have to do something completely different in order to achieve what I had in mind.

```
const test = [{
  Title: 'AAAA',
  Year: 'BBB',
  Runtime:'100min',
  Director:'CCC'
}]


const movies1 = test.map(({Title}) => Title, ({Year}) => Year)
console.log(movies1);
```

Comment: `const movies1 = [test[0].Title, test[0].Year]` or `const movies1 = test.flatMap(t => [t.Title, t.Year]);`

Comment: Can you try: `const movies1 = test.map((x) => [x.Title, x.Year])`

Comment: Your expected result seems to be a flat array. But this one returns a 2d. So I'm not sure

Comment: What should the result look like if there's more objects in `test`?

Comment: `test.flatMap(({Title,Year})=> [Title,Year]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to achieve this. `flatMap` is like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const test = [{
  Title: 'AAAA',
  Year: 'BBB',
  Runtime:'100min',
  Director:'CCC'
}]

const movies1 = test.flatMap(t => [t.Title, t.Year]);

console.log(movies1);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const test = [{
  Title: 'AAAA',
  Year: 'BBB',
  Runtime:'100min',
  Director:'CCC'
}]


const movies1 = test.map(({Title,Year}) => [Title,Year])
console.log(movies1);
```

Comment: This will give an array of arrays and not a single array which OP is looking for.